# URL with or without slash encounter a 404 Page error how to resolve it?

Tags: php, html, http-status-code-404

I have recently convert my site from PHP to html with same navigation

PROBLEM
In PHP all pages are ended-up with slash and in html its not the same because when i enter url address in browser with slash then 404 page error occur but without slash or extension it shows normal page.

how to resolve this issue

site/ page1 (normal)
site/ page1.html (normal)
site/ page1/ (404 Page error)

and i dont want to add extension because with extension PR is ZERO and with slash or without slash PR is 1.

Answer (score 0):

A simply research on the web would have guided you to a lot of stackoverflow question about this.

Just use .htaccess file with :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```